# Why Repeat Behavior did not work for my story board?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want my storyboard start over and over so i set Repeat Behavior="Forever"
but storyboard did not start again.

i try to put storyboard.completed but the debugger never enter this event 
why the storyboard is not ending i did not set repeat Behavior for any motion more that 1

my storyboard:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="napton" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Duration="0:0:3" Source="X" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="napton" RepeatBehavior="1x">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M351.5,142 L241,142"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Duration="0:0:3" Source="Y" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="napton" RepeatBehavior="1x">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M351.5,142 L241,142"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Duration="0:0:3" Source="Angle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="napton" RepeatBehavior="1x">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M351.5,142 L241,142"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="napton" RepeatBehavior="1x">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:12" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingPath BeginTime="0:0:3" Duration="0:0:2" Source="X" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="napton_back" RepeatBehavior="1x">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M526,134.5 L636.5,134.5"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingPath BeginTime="0:0:3" Duration="0:0:2" Source="Y" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="napton_back" RepeatBehavior="1x">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M526,134.5 L636.5,134.5"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="napton_back" RepeatBehavior="1x">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:12" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingPath BeginTime="0:0:5" Duration="0:0:7" Source="X" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="napton_orbit" RepeatBehavior="1x" Completed="Storyboard_
        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M636,140.25 C636,237.31404 525.07855,316 388.25,316 C251.42145,316 140.5,237.31404 140.5,140.25 C140.5,43.185955 251.42145,-35.5 388.25,-35.5 C525.07855,-35.5 636,43.185955 636,140.25 z"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingPath BeginTime="0:0:5" Duration="0:0:7" Source="Y" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="napton_orbit" RepeatBehavior="1x">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M636,140.25 C636,237.31404 525.07855,316 388.25,316 C251.42145,316 140.5,237.31404 140.5,140.25 C140.5,43.185955 251.42145,-35.5 388.25,-35.5 C525.07855,-35.5 636,43.185955 636,140.25 z"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="napton_orbit" RepeatBehavior="1x">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:12" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="napton_orbit" RepeatBehavior="1x">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5" Value="1"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:6.7" Value="1.5"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:8.5" Value="1"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:10.3" Value="0.5"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:12" Value="1"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="napton_orbit" RepeatBehavior="1x">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5" Value="1"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:6.7" Value="1.5"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:8.5" Value="1"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:10.3" Value="0.5"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:12" Value="1"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingPath BeginTime="0:0:5" Duration="0:0:2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="sun" RepeatBehavior="1x">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M2,-0.25 L104,1.25"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingPath BeginTime="0:0:5" Duration="0:0:2" Source="Y" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="sun" RepeatBehavior="1x">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M2,-0.25 L104,1.25"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="sun" RepeatBehavior="1x">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:7" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:12">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <Visibility>Hidden</Visibility>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingPath BeginTime="0:0:7" Duration="0:0:2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="sun_l" RepeatBehavior="1x">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M102.5,1.25 L-98.5,1.25"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingPath BeginTime="0:0:7" Duration="0:0:2" Source="Y" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="sun_l" RepeatBehavior="1x">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M102.5,1.25 L-98.5,1.25"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="sun_l" RepeatBehavior="1x">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:7" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:9" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:10">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <Visibility>Hidden</Visibility>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:12" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingPath BeginTime="0:0:9" Duration="0:0:3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="sun_back" RepeatBehavior="1x">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M-100,-0.25 L3.5,-0.25"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingPath BeginTime="0:0:9" Duration="0:0:3" Source="Y" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="sun_back" RepeatBehavior="1x">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M-100,-0.25 L3.5,-0.25"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="sun_back" RepeatBehavior="1x">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:9" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:12">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(TileBrush.TileMode)" Storyboard.TargetName="napton" RepeatBehavior="1x">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static TileMode.None}"/>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="{x:Static TileMode.None}"/>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="{x:Static TileMode.None}"/>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(TileBrush.Stretch)" Storyboard.TargetName="napton" RepeatBehavior="1x">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="{x:Static Stretch.Uniform}"/>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:12" Value="{x:Static Stretch.UniformToFill}"/>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingPath BeginTime="0:0:5" Duration="0:0:2" Source="Angle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="sun" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M2,-0.25 L104,1.25"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
</Storyboard>
```

result that i want to get is to make storyboard loop or know why storyboard is not ending .

Comment: Have you tried using only one animation and reproduce the issue? This way you will have a way to find out if it is Storyboard or the Animation it self.

Comment: no i did not try, i will, but Repeat Behavior should work for storyboard after its complete right, but storyboard never fire complete event <Storyboard completed="event_com"> never fired

Comment: Your last Animation has `RepeatBehavior="Forever"` so it will not complete

Comment: so if there is any "RepeatBehavior="Forever" storyboard will not fire complete event ...ok thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that the final `DoubleAnimationUsingPath` animation has the setting `RepeatBehavior="Forever"` so that animation will never end, therefore neither will the `Storyboard`.